Tampermonkey: This script was not executed yet
I have a tampermonkey script that doesn't fire on a page it should.  I click on the tampermonkey extension icon in the browser frame and I see my script (so the URL match is right).  I mouse over that and see:

This script was not executed yet

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling the extension in Chrome along with restarting Chrome (per the FAQ).
Any ideas on troubleshooting this? Could it be that onload never fires?  Is this a known issue?
Further, sometimes the script doesn't show up in the menu, as though the URL didn't match.
Tampermonkey v5.3.2 on Chrome 131.0.6778.86 64-bit.

"Any ideas on troubleshooting this?" Do you see any errors in your browser's developer console? It might be due to the site's Content Security Policy not allowing unknown scripts to run on the page. You'll see an error if that's the case. "sometimes the script doesn't show up" If you're using in on a Single Page Application which alters the URL without reloading the page during navigation, Tampermonkey won't pick it up unless you directly access the correct URL

Quoting Violentmonkey: "The script didn't exist or didn't match the URL when the page loaded, which
happens in Single-Page Application sites like fb or instagram that are using
fake navigation. You can reload the tab to run the script. To fix the script
use @match for the entire site and then detect changes using
MutationObserver or window.navigation API."

@blex Pretty sure it's a Single Page Application, but alterations to the URL are still within my match.  I get various console errors but they seem not to be coming from the tampermonkey extension, though it's very difficult to tell. And without my script even starting, my own console messages never fire.

@JimB the only times I've ever seen that message ("This script was not executed yet") is when the script is disabled. If the script is enabled and still not working, try creating a NEW script with the same headers and minimal code, or just post the full script.

@GTK Thank you! It is, in part, an enable issue. The tampermonkey extension menu has an "Enable" and I was mis-reading it. Definitely necessary, but it still seems to be a little inconsistent in how it fires. Still watching it for a while...

@JimB remember that the script is ran (matched) only on reload (hard navigation), SPA navigation does not re-run the script.
